# How to add a character after and before in string in Python?

Tags: python

I have two variable, one is string and other is list.

```
string_val = 'CreateTime:1557770979668  {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"subscriptionId\":\"//blp/mktdata/BLOOMBERG IDENTIFIER?fields=LAST_PRICE\",\"MarketDataEvents\":{\"LAST_PRICE\":50.84}}"}'
list_val = ["25746UCY3 Corp","BBG00JM9XLN6 Equity","CFM0987JKM Pro"]
```

In desired output, u can observe instead of 'BLOOMBERG IDENTIFIER', element of list_val is inserted. I have tried below code, but not get successful.

```
for i in range(0,len(list_val)):
    print(len(list_val))
    expect_val = string_val.split('mktdata/',0)[1]  + list_val[i] + string_val.split('?fields',0)[-1]
    print(expect_val)
```

Desired output:

```
CreateTime:1557770979668    {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"subscriptionId\":\"//blp/mktdata/25746UCY3 Corp?fields=LAST_PRICE\",\"MarketDataEvents\":{\"LAST_PRICE\":50.84}}"}
CreateTime:1557770979668    {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"subscriptionId\":\"//blp/mktdata/BBG00JM9XLN6 Equity?fields=LAST_PRICE\",\"MarketDataEvents\":{\"LAST_PRICE\":50.84}}"}
CreateTime:1557770979668    {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"subscriptionId\":\"//blp/mktdata/CFM0987JKM Pro?fields=LAST_PRICE\",\"MarketDataEvents\":{\"LAST_PRICE\":50.84}}"}
```

Please suggest, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `.replace(x, y)`:

```
string_val = 'CreateTime:1557770979668  {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"subscriptionId\":\"//blp/mktdata/BLOOMBERG IDENTIFIER?fields=LAST_PRICE\",\"MarketDataEvents\":{\"LAST_PRICE\":50.84}}"}'
list_val = ["25746UCY3 Corp","BBG00JM9XLN6 Equity","CFM0987JKM Pro"]
for x in list_val:
    print(string_val.replace('BLOOMBERG IDENTIFIER', x))
```

**Output:**

```
CreateTime:1557770979668  {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"subscriptionId":"//blp/mktdata/25746UCY3 Corp?fields=LAST_PRICE","MarketDataEvents":{"LAST_PRICE":50.84}}"}
CreateTime:1557770979668  {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"subscriptionId":"//blp/mktdata/BBG00JM9XLN6 Equity?fields=LAST_PRICE","MarketDataEvents":{"LAST_PRICE":50.84}}"}
CreateTime:1557770979668  {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"subscriptionId":"//blp/mktdata/CFM0987JKM Pro?fields=LAST_PRICE","MarketDataEvents":{"LAST_PRICE":50.84}}"}
```

Comment: thank u so much. One more query, what if I want to change the create time different at every row(randomly) and also the LAST_PRICE values(randomly)?

Comment: @ManishPal that becomes more tricky.  You can do another `replace` if you know the time (is the time constant) otherwise you will need to do regex to substitute it out. Same with last price. If you are just working with `string_val` and no other `str` than it is an easy.